# Sinatra-like web-framework for Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: web, sinatra, smalltalk, web-frameworks, pharo

Is there a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)-like web-framework for Pharo?

Or can the Zinc-HTTP-components do that more or less out-of-the-box?

Thanks!

Comment: A similar question is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513334/microframeworks-for-squeak-pharo-web-service/13691660)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, [Seaside-REST](http://code.google.com/p/seaside/wiki/SeasideRest) might also be interesting .

Comment: Thank you, I think it does what I want. It can be used to **serve web-pages** a la Sinatra. For interested users, read the chapter on REST services in the [online Seaside book](http://book.seaside.st/).

Answer (score 2):

I have been kindly pointed to **Ratpack** by Tim Felgentreff

http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/RatPack.html

He also has a github repository, probably with more up-to-date code:

https://github.com/timfel/ratpack

Comment: The ss3 version, as of Dec 2012, does not work with Pharo 1.4 out of the box. There are some deprecated methods and incompatibilities. Have not tried the github version yet.